# I want to know what "wmic os get name,version, csdversion" command returns for windows 10

Tags: command-line, windows-10

I want to know the result of following command for Windows 10 OS.

```
wmic os get Name,Version,CSDVersion /VALUE
```

Since, I don't have Windows 10 installed. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: have you tried that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have got following result when I have tried Command.

```
Caption=Microsoft windows 10 Pro Technical Preview
CSDVersion=
Version=10.0.09926
```